# Running script on windows server from windows 7 using python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to connect windows server using paramiko and the code is as

> host_script.py

```
import sys
import os

print os.name
import paramiko

# Connect to remote host
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect('XX.XX.XX.XX', username='admin', password='****')

# Setup sftp connection and transmit this script
sftp = client.open_sftp()
sftp.put(__file__, "C:\Users\Desktop\remote_server.py")
sftp.close()

# Run the transmitted script remotely without args and show its output.
# SSHClient.exec_command() returns the tuple (stdin,stdout,stderr)
stdout = client.exec_command('python /tmp/remote_server.py')[1]
for line in stdout:
    # Process each line in the remote output
    print line

client.close()
sys.exit(0)
```

and the file which I want to run on server is having the following code

> remote_server.py

```
import logging
from pywinauto import application
pwa_app = application.Application()
pwa_app.start_('notepad.exe')
logging.warning("Application successfully opened")
```

Now when I try running this code through host terminal the code just run without error and no output.

Can someone let me know which part I am missing.

Comment: Please remove the extra indent from your code. You have Python 2.7 and Python 3 in your tags, yet you're using Python 2.x syntax. Which is it?

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack corrected, thanks

Comment: `sftp.put(__file__, "C:\Users\Desktop\remote_server.py")` and `stdout = client.exec_command('python /tmp/remote_server.py')[1]`. Why are the paths different?

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack Path is different because I don't want to store the host file in server file and will be there in temp folder to run.

Comment: @cyborg Does this command `client.exec_command("cmd /c dir")` prints result?

Comment: @Samuel No, it is not giving any result, also I have cygwin installed in both the system so whether it can help in anyway, though I havenot tried yet

Comment: @cyborg Ok, and this `client.exec_command("ipconfig")` ?

Comment: @Samuel, No It has not given output and I think there is some problem with paramiko here, I am looking into that and will let u know soon

Comment: @cyborg if you upload the script to `C:\Users\Desktop`, how are you expecting to run it in `/tmp`? Further `/tmp` is not a WIndows path. What SSH server are you running on your Windows box?